# Why same image menu has different transition in different sites using firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering why in mozilla firefox the same image menu has different way of transition on different sites.
If you use firefox and go to this link and then hover over different pictures you will get to know how it moves http://www.alohatechsupport.net/examples/image-menu-2.html
after doing that go to this link http://bloghutsbeta.blogspot.com/2012/04/testing-main.html and hover over images and see how it moves.

In both cases the transition effect is same but in one it is slow (hanging) while in other it is smooth. I didn't presented the Markup as the both are identical but still if you feel like let me know in comments I will edit it to provide you with as much relevant data as possible and required.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="files.cryoffalcon.com/javascript/…; 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $().ready(function() { 
        $('.jimgMenu ul').kwicks({
            max: 310, 
            duration: 300, 
            easing: 'easeOutQuad', 
            complete: 'callback'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In the second link there is over 600 lines of javascript, including several `document.ready` handlers, not to mention external scripts. I would imagine that page is slow due to the weight of javascript in it. It really is a mess.

Comment: Well what do you think if whole scripts are combined into one, is it good? what should be the maximum size for an external script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try and check how each is configured? It could be that the plugin had options for easing.

Anyways, it could also be affected by the number of elements in that showcase. More elements means more DOM nodes to animate, and everyone knows DOM manipulation is an expensive operation. This could lead to choppy, non-smooth animation.

Also, the number of elements itself might affect animation. The other one has a less slides per width (loose) while the other has more slides per width (cramped). This also affects your perception of the same animation.

Comment: Well if we put elements as a reason I guess you would be right as one got 10 images while other one has 5. Yes this plugin do have options for easing , I will add the easing options to the answer.

Comment: sorry I was not able to add it as I have 5KB/s internet living in afghanistan so I don't see those brackets to put code, if I put it like this people will starting giving it negative rating, so I will add the code here in comment <script type="text/javascript" src="http://files.cryoffalcon.com/javascript/jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
 $('.jimgMenu ul').kwicks({max: 310, duration: 300, easing: 'easeOutQuad', complete: 'callback'});
 });
</script>

Comment: @CryOfFaclon if both have exactly the same JS code and configurations, it boils down to the DOM manipulations causing the difference. Also, I see shadows on the other showcase. As far as I know, some CSS3 styles like shadows cause choppy animations.

Comment: Well you are right that could be the reason except DOM. Now I understand. Can you tell me something what is standard size for an external javscript file, as I got lots of javascript code and I am planning to combine them and make them external

Comment: @CryOfFaclon there is no standard in size, just make it as small as you can. Use a compressor like [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) or [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

Answer (score 0):

I am using FireFox 10 and I do not experience any hanging at all trying both your pages. The second one might be animating slower when the whole page is not fully loaded yet. But once all elements are loaded they have pretty the same transition speed.

Comment: Well maybe it might be because of slow internet or computer, but I thought it is for everyone.